# Does exposing a Combine publisher of an actor as a nonisolated property violate the thread-safety of the actor?

Tags: thread-safety, swift-concurrency

In the following example, the private `_valuePublisher` has been exposed as a type-erased `Publisher` through a `nonisolated` property. Additionally, the current value of the `_valuePublisher` is also exposed as a `nonisolated` property. The compiler is happy with this arrangement but I'm not sure about the thread-safety aspect of this especially for the `unwrappedValue` property. Any thoughts?

```swift
final actor MyActor {
    
    private let _valuePublisher = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(0)
    
    nonisolated var valuePublisher: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
        _valuePublisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    nonisolated var unwrappedValue: Int {
        _valuePublisher.value
    }
    
    func updateValue(_ value: Int) {
        _valuePublisher.send(value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked:

> Does exposing a Combine publisher of an actor as a nonisolated property violate the thread-safety of the actor?

Technically, this actor has no mutable state and thus presents no thread-safety risk; the risk rests in the referenced `CurrentValueSubject`.

However, if you give the actor a mutable state (by making the actor’s property a `var` instead of `let`) and try to expose that via a non-isolated property, that results in errors, as that would threaten the thread-safety of the actor, itself:

> Actor-isolated property '_valuePublisher' can not be referenced from a non-isolated context

E.g.:

[image]

In short, in the original code snippet, the actor’s property was immutable, so the potential risk rests in the thread-safety of the referenced class, not in that of the actor.

---

That having been said, there is a thread-safety issue here.

To have the compiler perform more robust checks, I would advise changing the “Strict Concurrency Checking” setting to “Complete”:

[image: “strict concurrency checking” setting to “complete”]

When you do this, it will warn you of the problems:

> Non-sendable type 'CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>' in asynchronous access to actor-isolated property '_valuePublisher' cannot cross actor boundary

E.g.:

[image: compiler warnings]

Comment: For those unfamiliar with “sendable” types, see WWDC 2022 video [Eliminate data races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110351/). It’s a primer on “sendable” types and has links to related videos.